# Lenses & Scopes - Is it possible to copy content by clicking on it in the Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, scopes

I just got an idea to create a lense that would work as a Character Map. I need character copying very often, and on Windows there was a very useful programme (PopChar), but on Ubuntu I haven't found anything like it. So I thought I could try to build a lense that could copy a single character (or perhaps a sequence of characters, if possible?) by just searching for it in the Dash and clicking on it once found. Since I've never done anything similar, I'm not sure how possible it is to copy certain content by clicking on its visual link in the Dash.

So, my question is, if I create a Lense + Scope for copying Unicode characters, would it be possible through Dash to just copy a character that I click on once I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope's **activate_uri** method could be used to copy text to the system clipboard with the following:

```
clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clipboard.set_text('text', -1)
clipboard.store()
```

Comment: Teester thank you so much for the answer. I'm not able at the moment to test this out, but I certainly will as soon as time permits me to. For now I'll accept your answer and I'll return with the feedback as soon as I test it out.